# Closure compiler not renaming properties and methods (advanced compilation)

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Why doesn't Closure Compiler rename my `path`, `start`, etc properties, but it does rename my `limit` property when using advanced compilation?

I want it to rename every property and method in my code, except the exported constructor `window.RFM`.

Here is the constructor snippet:

```
var RFM = function(node) {
    ...
    this.path = '/';
    this.limit = 10;
    ...
};
```

Which gets compiled to:

```
    ...
    this.path = '/';
    this.c = 10;
    ...
```

I have tried adding annotations like `@private` and `@constructor`, but it had no effect.

I have been testing on http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/

Here is the full code:

```
(function() {
var ajax = {};
ajax.x = function() {
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
    } catch (e1) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
        } catch (e2) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
    }
};

ajax.send = function(url, callback, method, data, sync) {
    var x = ajax.x();
    x.open(method, url, sync);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4) {
            callback(x.responseText)
        }
    };
    if (method == 'POST') {
        x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }
    x.send(data)
};

ajax.get = function(url, data, callback, sync) {
    var query = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
    }
    ajax.send(url + '?' + query.join('&'), callback, 'GET', null, sync)
};

ajax.post = function(url, data, callback, sync) {
    ajax.send(url, callback, 'POST', data, sync)
};


var RFM = function(node) {
    this.node = node;
    node.innerHTML = this.template(RFM.templates.dialog);

    this.nodeFiles = node.getElementsByClassName('rfm-files')[0];
    this.nodeDirectories = node.getElementsByClassName('rfm-directories')[0];
    this.nodeTags = node.getElementsByClassName('rfm-tags')[0];

    this.nodeDirectories.addEventListener('click', this.clickedDirectory.bind(this));

    this.path = '/';
    this.start = 0;
    this.limit = 10;
    this.sort = 'mtime';
    this.direction = 'desc';
    this.src = 'example.php';

    this.refresh();
};

RFM.prototype.template = function(string, variables) {
    return string.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, function(match, variable) {
        return variables[variable];
    }).replace(/_(.*?)_/g, function(match, variable) {
        return locale[variable];
    });
};

// Refresh
RFM.prototype.refresh = function() {
    ajax.get(this.src, {
        path: this.path,
        start: this.start,
        limit: this.limit,
        sort: this.sort,
        direction: this.direction
    }, function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        this.refreshFiles(data.files);
        this.refreshDirectories(data.directories);
    }.bind(this), false);
};

RFM.prototype.refreshFiles = function(files) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        files[i].type = files[i].name.replace(/^.*\./, '');
        files[i].mtime = new Date(files[i].mtime * 1000).toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace(/.{5}$/, '');
        result += this.template(RFM.templates.file, files[i]);
    }
    this.nodeFiles.innerHTML = result;
};

RFM.prototype.refreshDirectories = function(directories) {
    var result = '';
    if (this.path != '/') {
        result += this.template(RFM.templates.directory, {
            name: '..'
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
        result += this.template(RFM.templates.directory, {
            name: directories[i]
        });
    }
    this.nodeDirectories.innerHTML = result;
};

// Events
RFM.prototype.clickedDirectory = function(e) {
    if (e.target.innerText === '..') {
        this.path = this.path.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/$/, '/');
    } else {
        this.path += e.target.innerText + '/';
    }
    this.refresh();
};

var locale = {
    headingDirectories: 'Directories',
    headingTags: 'Tags',
    headingUpload: 'Upload',
    headingFiles: 'Files',
    fileName: 'Name',
    fileSize: 'Size',
    fileType: 'Type',
    fileModificationTime: 'Modified'
};

RFM.templates = {
    "dialog": "<div class=\"rfm-dialog\"> <div class=\"rfm-wrapper\"> <div class=\"rfm-sidebar\"> <div class=\"rfm-directories-wrapper\"> <span class=\"rfm-heading\">_headingDirectories_<\/span> <div class=\"rfm-directories\"><\/div> <\/div> <div class=\"rfm-tag-wrapper\"> <span class=\"rfm-heading\">_headingTags_<\/span> <div class=\"rfm-tags\"><\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div class=\"rfm-main\"> <div class=\"rfm-upload\"> <span class=\"rfm-heading\">_headingUpload_<\/span> <\/div> <div class=\"rfm-files-wrapper\"> <span class=\"rfm-heading\">_headingFiles_<\/span> <table class=\"rfm-table\"> <thead> <tr> <th><\/th> <th class=\"rfm-file-name\">_fileName_<\/th> <th class=\"rfm-file-type\">_fileType_<\/th> <th class=\"rfm-file-size\">_fileSize_<\/th> <th class=\"rfm-file-mtime\">_fileModificationTime_<\/th> <\/tr> <\/thead> <tbody class=\"rfm-files\"> <\/tbody> <\/table> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <div>",
    "directory": "<div class=\"rfm-directory\">{name}<\/div>",
    "file": "<tr class=\"rfm-file\"> <td><\/td> <td class=\"rfm-file-name\">{name}<\/td> <td class=\"rfm-file-type\">{type}<\/td> <td class=\"rfm-file-size\">{size}<\/td> <td class=\"rfm-file-mtime\">{mtime}<\/td> <\/tr>"
};
window['RFM'] = RFM;
})();
```

And the compiled:

```
(function() {
  function b(a) {
    a.innerHTML = this.a(b.b.k);
    this.h = a.getElementsByClassName("rfm-files")[0];
    this.d = a.getElementsByClassName("rfm-directories")[0];
    this.d.addEventListener("click", this.e.bind(this));
    this.path = "/";
    this.start = 0;
    this.c = 10;
    this.sort = "mtime";
    this.direction = "desc";
    this.src = "example.php";
    this.refresh()
  }
  ...
  window.RFM = b
})();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Closure Compiler not rename objects with certain names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671041/why-does-closure-compiler-not-rename-objects-with-certain-names)

Answer (score 0):

Property names that are defined in (the default) externs will not be renamed unless aliasExternals is used.

So sort, getElementById, parseInt and lots of others will not be renamed. I guess the compiler should see your properties as properties of RFM but it seems that it doesnt. If you rename path to myPath it should be renamed or use aliasExternals when compiling.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Properties names defined in externs will not be renamed unless the type-based optimizations are enabled (which are off by default). See https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Some_of_my_properties_are_getting_renamed,_but_some_aren't.